# Why I have undefined on array on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm in the middle of a simple app, the idea is to randomly pick up without repeating the values ​​of an array.

I managed to do it through a function but at the moment I started to go through it I got two undefined and I do not know why

Sample of code :

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

cont = 0;
totalnum = num.length - 1;

function next() {
  var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cont < totalnum ? ++cont : 0));
  var number = num[indice];
  document.getElementById("hola2").innerHTML = num.splice(indice, 1);
}
```

Comment: You could try to shuffle the array, then loop over it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `splice()` changes the length of the array just use length of `num` each time to get the random index and you don't need the other variables

```js
var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function next() {
  if (!num.length) return;// do something when no more exist

  var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length);
  var number = num.splice(indice, 1);
  document.getElementById("hola2").innerHTML = number;
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', next)
```

```html
<div id="hola2"></div>
<button id="btn">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of `totalnum` only once at the start and not updating it, even as you are using `splice` to remove entries from the array. So after a few calls of `next()` you are more and more likely to access indices of the array that are now `undefined` because they've been spliced out. You need to update the value of `totalnum` as you go or simply refer to the array length directly (I prefer to use the latter as it is simpler, more intuitive, and readable).

```
<script>
    var num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    cont = 0;

    function next() {

        var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cont < num.length ?++cont:0));
        var number = num[indice];
        document.getElementById("hola2").innerHTML =num.splice(indice,1);

    }
</script>
```